# Изображения из галереи не загружаются на некоторых смартфонах

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, mobile-development

Создаю приложение для сохранения данных аккаунтов,в приложении присутствует функция добавления собственных изображений. Проводя тест на разных устройствах заметил, что некоторые(zte blade a7 2020 android 10.0, xiaomi redmi 5 android 8.1.0) смартфоны не загружают изображения. Путь к изображению сохраняется в базе данных, изображения загружаются с помощью Glide, Picasso.

[image: Вот скриншот со смартфона, где изображения добавляются]

[image: Здесь изображения не загружаются]

[Вот ссылка на репозиторий с приложением](https://github.com/VildanAb/AccountInfoSaver)

Заранее спасибо за помощь!

Comment: приложите код в вопрос пожалуйста, по ссылкам переходить тут не особо любят!

Comment: Начните с того, что уточните какие это "некоторые" телефоны? Модель, версия Android. Потому что некоторый это понятие очень растяжимое. Так же приложите нужный код, весь ваш репозиторий никто смотреть не захочет. Хотите получить помощь, научитесь ценить время других, а это значит, что приложите минимальную но необходимую информацию по , чтоб можно было дать ответ на ваш вопрос. Как задать хороший вопрос -> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask